# How to get daylight saving settings programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dst

Some countries are observing daylight saving, so I want to know if daylight setting is currently turned on or off `(TRUE or FALSE)` on the iDevice then I could correct the date on my app. is that possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate this: `correct the date on my app`. Since `NSDate` is a simply a point in time without any time zone, users will see that date in their time zone, which is the expected behavior in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query the current [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html)s [`timeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/timeZone) to see if it is currently in [daylight saving time](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/isDaylightSavingTime).

```
BOOL dst = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] timeZone] isDaylightSavingTime];
```