# How to get daylight saving settings of a specific date?

Tags: cocoa, dst

For example I have this day `2014-08-08 12:00AM` which is of course, true under daylight saving in the US.. how do I get the value of `TRUE` on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get daylight saving settings programmatically in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152954/how-to-get-daylight-saving-settings-programmatically-in-xcode)

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866725/iphone-current-date-considering-daylight-saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152954/how-to-get-daylight-saving-settings-programmatically-in-xcode) to you, but use [`isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/isDaylightSavingTime) instead.

```
NSDate *date; // Store your date 2014-08-08 12:00AM
BOOL dst = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] timeZone] isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:date];
```